# Do I need to "keep the electrons moving occasionally" in my laptop battery?

Tags: batteries

I read this:

http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MC556LL/B/will-it-hurt-my-macbook-pro-if-i-leave-the-power-supply-plugged-in-to-the-wall-socket-and-in-to-my-2011-macbook-pro-at-all-times-mostly/Q4X77ADTHJX977UJD

Apparently, to maintain my laptop battery, I need to keep the electrons moving occasionally. Are they suggesting that electrons decay? It sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: Electrons are always moving when the laptop is operating. That's what electric current is: a flow of charge. I suspect, thought, that that's just a euphemism. The recommendation may be based on how batteries age.

Comment: @HDE226868  Isn't it true that when plugged in and if the battery is fully charge, the laptop directs power directly from the socket (i.e. bypassing the battery)?

Comment: To be very honest with you... the electrons don't care. The battery degrades mostly trough cycling, so if you keep your laptop plugged in all the time, it should be fine. If it isn't, then sure as heck Apple engineers screwed up the charger circuit or firmware.

Answer (score 1):

> **Are they suggesting**

In this case *they* means some random contributor (Gary S from Jacksonville Beach), not official Apple advice.

> **that electrons decay?**

No, the person who provided the answer was being euphemistic. Some battery chemistries require that the battery not be left in a fully discharged state, some that it not be left in a partially discharged state. Rechargeable batteries have a limited life and most require some care in how they are charged, discharged and stored.

> **keep the electrons moving occasionally**

In reality,

- electrons are always moving
- usually, the charge carriers in batteries are ions, not electrons.

The problem is chemical effects, not charge carrier motion as such.